# Slim Framework redirect outside of a route (if database fails)

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

This is my database class:

```
<?php
// Database class
final class Database {
  private static $instance = null;
  public $db;
  private function __construct() {
        global $config;
        global $app;
        $config = (object) $config["database"];
        try {
          $dsn = sprintf("%s:hostname=%s;dbname=%s;", $config->driver, $config->host, $config->dbname);
          $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $config->username, $config->password);
          $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
          $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // stop app
         // Redirect to /error/database
        }
  }

  public static function getDb() {
    if(Database::$instance == null) Database::$instance = new Database();
    return Database::$instance->db;
  }
}
```

Now, if the database connection fails, I would like to redirect the user to `/error/database`.

However, it doesn't redirect. I have tried

```
header("Location: /error/database");
```

And

```
$app->redirect("/error/database");
```

I also tried creating a custom error handler (with `$app->error(function() { ... });` and in the catch `$app->error` however it returns `NULL`?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586786/how-can-i-deliver-an-error-page-in-slim-framework-when-an-exception-is-thrown-ou) did not work for me, maybe because it use SlimFramework 2 and I'm using 3?

Comment: Why stll using pdo. use redbeanphp orm built on pdo

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I have added a middelware

```
 // add a middleware, check if we have a database connection
 $app->add(function($req, $res, $next) use($app) {
   if(Database::getDb() == null &&
      !preg_match("/error/", $req->getUri())) {
     return $res
             ->withStatus(500)
             ->withHeader("Location", $app
                                       ->getContainer()
                                       ->router
                                       ->pathFor("error-database"));
   }

   return $next($req, $res);
 });
```